# MS Edge + position:sticky w/textarea bug?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Given a content area with a `max-height` and `overflow:auto`, and a footer is `position:sticky` so that it will always appear on the page, Edge seems to be misbehaving. This works fine in other browsers (latest IE, Chrome, FF). Specifically, with a `textarea` in the content `div`, the footer is improperly placed until text is entered into the `textarea`.

Is there a browser-specific method for working with MS Edge and sticky divs, or is this just a browser bug? If the latter, any thoughts on a workaround?

Update for Edge Version:
Microsoft Edge 44.17763.771.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <br /><br />
    <textarea></textarea>
    <p>
      Enter some text to watch this break
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="sticky">Sticky</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: black;
}
#container {
  max-height: 300px;
  background: cyan;
  overflow: auto;
}
#content {
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: white;
}
#sticky {
  padding: 15px;
  background: grey;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This is available as a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n61ua5xs/1/)

Comment: It's working properly in all my browsers: *(Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Opera)*

Comment: I've updated the post with the affected version of Edge. It's likely that you have a different version.

Comment: I tested it on Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 - Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134.

Comment: broken in Microsoft Edge 44.17763.771.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763

Comment: I have created [a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/40suwnhm/) using your code on Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362, it seems that everything works well, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVxQh.gif). You could try to create a new application to test it. and reset the Edge browser setting, If still not working, perhaps it is an issue in Edge 44.17763.771.0, and it has fixed on Edge 44.18362 version. You could try to upgrade the Edge browser version to the latest version.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I see the OP's problem in the fiddle in Edge 44.18362.387.0. This is under Windows 10, 64 bit; would that matter?

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT used significantly more content. It appears that once the height of the container reaches max-height, the problem is not present.

Comment: `@thatthatisis and  @Mr Lister`, I think I have reproduced the problem, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWq3L.gif), right? But if the content div contains enough content, after the scroll appears,this issue will disappear (like my [previous sample](http://jsfiddle.net/40suwnhm/)). It can be possible a Microsoft Edge browser bug. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue. As a temporary workaround, I suggest you could add more content in the content div. If I get any feedback or solution than I will try to provide you in future. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT - Yes, that's it. I provided a very precise example so that no one would have to work to reproduce it. "Add more content" is not a solution when working with dynamic content. The specific use case actually calls for a div that is as small as possible with a max-height of a certain section of the layout. Adding more content to expand the div violates the spec of "as small as possible".

Comment: Agree with you, you could reduce the max-height value(such as: 180px).